# what are the different cases of return during recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I have problem in code during compilation. 
what could be the problem in given code of the question:

Given an array of ints, compute recursively if the array contains a 6. We'll use the convention of considering only the part of the array that begins at the given index. In this way, a recursive call can pass index+1 to move down the array. The initial call will pass in index as 0.

`enter code here`

```
   array6([1, 6, 4], 0) → true
    array6([1, 4], 0) → false
    array6([6], 0) → true
    public boolean array6(int[] nums, int index) {
      if(index==(nums.length)) return false;
      if(nums[index]==6) return true;
      array6(nums,index+1);
    }
```

i expect output in boolean but actual output is missing return statement line:6

Comment: `return array6(nums,index+1);`

Comment: `I have problem in code during compilation` Including the full error message would be very useful (although in this case it is pretty obvious)

Answer (score 0):

When you recursively call `array6(nums, index + 1)`, you have to return the value that it returns.